# DataGrip diagrams show all tables on top of each other

Tags: datagrip

When I visualize my schema in a diagram, all the tables are shown [like in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pca6Q.png), this didn't use to happen before.

All the relations and arrows work, but its very annoying to arrange the tables on my own.

Maybe it is a setting I moved by accident?

Comment: Does it help to disable custom plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug. Try playing with the layout:

[image]